# Sort array by date

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

My array has an array for each field (i.e date, name, etc.). How do I sort the array by date? Should I create another array? Can I use sort or unsort here. If yes, how? Here is my array:

```
Array
(
    [date] => Array
        (
            [0] => 03/11/2019
            [1] => 03/19/2019
            [2] => 03/15/2019
            [3] => 12/15/2018
        )

    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => Lowa
            [1] => Stephanie
            [2] => Allan
            [3] => Joffer
        )

    [number] => Array
        (
            [0] => 178989898
            [1] => 111111111
            [2] => 222222222
            [3] => 333333333
        )

    [unit] => Array
        (
            [0] => HR
            [1] => VPP
            [2] => 
            [3] => OAT
        )

    [department] => Array
        (
            [0] => Chemistry
            [1] => IT
            [2] => Lab
            [3] => Contractor
        )

)
```

At the end, my first element will be:
`03/19/2019 Stephanie 111111111 VPP IT`

Comment: You organised your data in the wrong way. Things that belong together should be in the same array. You have it transposed.

Comment: @trincot is correct, I was just adding the same sentence...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your data can be better organized:

```
$newArr = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 03/11/2019
            [name] => Lowa
            [number] => 178989898
            [unit] => HR
            [department] => Chemistry
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 03/19/2019
            [name] => Stephanie
            [number] => 111111111
            [unit] => VPP
            [department] => IT
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 03/15/2019
            [name] => Allan
            [number] => 222222222
            [unit] =>
            [department] => Lab
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [date] => 12/15/2018
            [name] => Joffer
            [number] => 333333333
            [unit] => OAT
            [department] => Contractor
        )
);
```

Then, you can simply sort it by:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
  if ($a["date"] == $b["date"]) return 0;
  return ($a["date"] < $b["date"]) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($newArr, "cmp");
```

Please be warned that dates in the format "Month/Day/Year" ar not alphabetically sortable.
You definitively should use a Year/Month/Day format for your dates, or write a more specific `cmp()` function...

**UPDATE**: To answer OP's question in comment: just reverse $row and 'field' order:

```
for ($row = 0; $row < count($date); $row++) {
  $newArr[$row]['date'] = $date[$row];
  $newArr[$row]['name'] = $name[$row];
  ...
}
```

Comment: how do I get my array in right format?  ````   for ($row = 0; $row < count($date); $row++) {
       
        $newArr['date'][$row]= $date[$row] ;
        $newArr['name'][$row]= $name[$row] ;
        $newArr['number'][$row]= $number[$row] ;
        $newArr['unit'][$row]= $unit[$row] ;
        $newArr['department'][$row]= $department[$row] ;
           
        }````

Comment: @Maple: Please see the update to my answer to see how to get your array in a better format...

Answer (score 1):

First save the keys of your array - then by using `array_value` convert to integer keys so you can use the `...` operator.

Then you can use `array_filter` with `null` function to re-organize your array. Next step will be to get the keys back using `array_map` and `array_combine`.

Last step - sort by "data" with `usort`

Consider the following example:

```
$arr = ["date" => ["3", "7", "5"], "name" => ["aa", "bb", "cc"]]; // this can have a lot more sub-array inside
$keys = array_keys($arr); // extract the keys for later use
$res = array_map(null, ...array_values($arr)); // transposed the array
$res = array_map(function ($e) use ($keys) {return array_combine($keys, $e);}, $res); // return the keys to the transposed array
usort($res, function ($a, $b) {return strcmp($a['date'], $b['date']);} ); // sort all by "date"
```

Reference:

[array-keys](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php), [array-filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php), [array-map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php), [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php), [array-values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

**Notice** @MarcoS post comment regarding the comparing dates